# Using 100% Off Coupon Codes with Charge

Tags: charge

I'm trying to implement a 100% off coupon code with Charge, but every time I submit the form I get an error.

The error reads: 
Fatal error: Call to a member function addError() on a non-object in /system/expressionengine/third_party/charge/mod.charge.php on line 1387

Any clue how I could resolve this? Would the charge_pre_payment hook work? And if so, how/where would I implement that?

Thanks in advance, EE Harbor has been unresponsive to any of my report requests.